# Setting up Enterprise Application

Tags: java, netbeans, ejb, war

So, I'm setting up my first Enterprise Application project and I got some issues with it, which I think is some kind of configuration that I don't know.

I have the following structure on my project:

- Application
- Application-ejb
- Application-war

The Application contains within the other two. in my ejb I have some model classes and a couple of persistence with some simple SQLite. In my war I have just `index.jsp` and two servlet classes.  In these servlet classes I try to instantiate a object from the EJB.  On compile it's fine, but when I try to run I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

When I try to run the application the Glassfish server reports the following:

```
INFO:   visiting unvisited references
INFO:   visiting unvisited references
SEVERE:   Class [ Lbr/edu/horario/persistence/DisciplinaManager; ] not found. Error while loading [ class br.edu.horario.servlets.disciplinaServlet ]
INFO:   visiting unvisited references
INFO:   Loading application [horarioApplication#horarioApplication-war.war] at [horarioApplication-war]
INFO:   horarioApplication foi implantado com sucesso em 322 milissegundos.
WARNING:   Context path from ServletContext: /horarioApplication-war differs from path from bundle: horarioApplication-war
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[disciplinaServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet disciplinaServlet threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: br/edu/horario/persistence/DisciplinaManager
    at br.edu.horario.servlets.disciplinaServlet.processRequest(disciplinaServlet.java:50)
    at br.edu.horario.servlets.disciplinaServlet.doGet(disciplinaServlet.java:74)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.edu.horario.persistence.DisciplinaManager
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1761)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
    ... 31 more
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is the Application-ejb.jar file listed in the application.xml file in the META-INF dir of the ear file? Is the Application-ejb.jar in the root of the ear file?

Comment: Yes it was, but I gave up using this way, for some reason the SQLite was causing the error, now I'm using JPA. But thanks!