# Glassfish: Deployment Configuration for this project not found

Tags: netbeans, deployment, configuration, glassfish, web.xml

I'm trying to fix a [glassfish warning: context path differs from bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740363/) but cannot, at least through the IDE, create a [glassfish-web.xml](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beaql.html) file:

> Deployment Configuration for this project not found. Deployment
>   descriptor version could not be set properly.

[image: Deployment Configuration for this project not Found.]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a glassfish-web.xml. In your project, you already have a web.xml which is all you need. Check in that file to see if your context root has a leading "/".

You can also set your context root in the servlet itself, so check to see what the context root is in there. You may find that one has a leading slash and the other doesn't.

Comment: I didn't see a context in web.xml (?).  I googled and saw eclipse users were clicking on project properties, so I stumbled across "solution" which I posted as an answer.  Netbeans sometimes makes me want to swear.  Thank you for the help.  Should there be a context element in web.xml?

Comment: Setting the context root through the web.xml is optional. You might find Oracle's official Java EE 7 tutorial useful: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ There's a downloadable PDF/epub etc link in the top right, so you can search for things like web.xml and see what it's supposed to be used for.

Answer (score 1):

glassfish-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/CRM</context-root>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
     <context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
<param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

NB, so, something something sometimes.  Selecting the Web component project, right click, run, change context:

[image: run context]

as far as I can tell, this caused the generation of `glassfish-web.xml` which was the problem to begin with...

Anyhow, now it runs with astonishing output:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ lynx http://localhost:8080/CRM/crm.xhtml -dump
   some details go here


thufir@doge:~$
```